# SQL Server Pivot weighted average

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Need to calculate average selling price.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50),Qty INT, Price REAL, [Month] VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('A',10 ,3,'JAN'),
('A',100,2,'JAN'),
('B',20 ,1,'JAN'),
('A',100,1,'FEB'),
('B',100,2,'FEB')

SELECT* FROM (SELECT Item, (Price*Qty) Price,[Month] FROM @t )t
PIVOT(SUM(Price) for [Month] in ([JAN],[FEB]))pvt
```

The result for above is

```
Item    JAN  FEB
A       230  100
B       20   200
```

I need weighted average.  The result I need is below.

```
Item    JAN  FEB
A       2.09 1.00
B       1.00 2.00
```

Item A Jan = (3*10+2*100)/(10+100)=2.09

I use SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `sum()` again after the `pivot`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select Item, round(sum(Price*Qty*1.00) /sum(Qty * 1.00), 2) as price, [Month] FROM @t GROUP BY Item, [Month])t
PIVOT(SUM(Price) for [Month] in ([JAN],[FEB]))pvt
```

**Result:**

[image]

**To format with decimal:**

```
SELECT Item, cast([JAN] as numeric(9,2)) as JAN, cast([FEB] as numeric(9,2)) as FEB  FROM 
(select Item, sum(Price*Qty) /sum(Qty) as Price, [Month] FROM @t GROUP BY Item, [Month])t
PIVOT(SUM(Price) for [Month] in ([JAN],[FEB]))pvt
```

**Result:**

[image]